# Writing a string at the end of a line in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I want to write a string at the end of every line in a text file. Basically I want to add Minx and Maxx values and append the result at the end of the line. With my code, it only adds the min and max of the first line and appends it on a new line at the end of the file. What's the easiest way to implement this in Python?

Text file contains something like this:

```
Distance1Mean1=5.40530mm StDev1=0.00543 Median1=5.40392mm Min1=5.39694mm Max1=5.41789mm DeltaMeanMedian1=0.00138mm DeltaMax1=0.02095mm NumberOfReadings=33, 
Distance2Mean2=6.40218mm StDev2=0.00226 Median2=6.40239mm Min2=6.39890mm Max2=6.40588mm DeltaMeanMedian2=-0.00021mm DeltaMax2=0.00698mm NumberOfReadings=33,*
```

My code:

```
with open("Example1.txt", "r+") as f:
#line=f.readline()
    string=[]
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Distance'):
            word1=line[63:70]
            word2=line[78:85]
            string = [line[63:70], line[78:85]]
            a = float(string[0])
            b = float(string[1])
            c = a + b
            f.write(str(c))
f.close()
```

Comment: Example output?

Comment: Distance1Mean1=5.40530mm StDev1=0.00543 Median1=5.40392mm Min1=5.39694mm Max1=5.41789mm DeltaMeanMedian1=0.00138mm DeltaMax1=0.02095mm NumberOfReadings=33, Min1 + Max1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `end` kwarg of print, like this:

```
for x in range(5):
    print('Line'+str(x),end=' Are you still there?\n')
```

This produces an output:

```
Line0 Are you still there?
Line1 Are you still there?
Line2 Are you still there?
Line3 Are you still there?
Line4 Are you still there?
```

I believe this is applicable to your problem.